# Flutter text data if coming null?

Tags: flutter

There is such a code and if the user is logged in as a visitor, it prints null because there is no e-mail information, how can I show it blank?

```
 Text(
    '$successmail \n\n'  
    style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 22.0,
    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    color: Colors.black,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    ),
    ),
```

I tried putting things like question marks at the end of the variable but I don't know how to do it exactly.

Comment: '$successmail \n\n' -> successmail == null || successmail.isEmpty ? '' : '$successmail \n\n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On text widget try this:
`"${sucessful ?? "No email"} \n \n"`

Comment: Hi, how can i use on this example ?  i try this way but its doesnt work.
`image: NetworkImage(                                           "https://example.com/${companies.file1 ?? "0.png"}") `

Comment: you can use `companies.file1 != null ? NetworkImage("yourLink") : NetworkImage("YourOtherLink")`

Answer (score 2):

```
successmail == null ? SizedBox.shrink : Text(
    '$successmail \n\n'  
    style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 22.0,
    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    color: Colors.black,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    ),
    ),
```

try this way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Text(
  '${sucessful ?? "No email"} \n \n'  
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 22.0,
    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    color: Colors.black,
    letterSpacing: 0,
  ),
),
```